# Calling Listview from MainPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile

I am trying to call my ListView from the mainpage. The data that holds the description of items in the list is in a class named datamodel.  When I deploy the application I am not able to view the list. The application does not deploy. I'm really not sure what angle to start, I am going from examples in a Xamarin Forms book to create a scrollable list with text and detail for each row in the list.

```
    public MainPage()
    {

        Picker picker = new Picker
        {
            Title = "Movies",

            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };
        //

        DataModel thisList = new DataModel();
        ListView myListView = thisList.ListViewGrouped();

        var options = new List<string> {
            "Kill Bill", "Matrix", "Zombieland", "The Dark Knight", "Terminator", "Apocalypse Now", "Resouvoir dogs", "Horrible Bosses", "The Breakup", "Wedding Crashers", };
        picker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            pickmovie = picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex];

        };
        foreach (string optionName in options) picker.Items.Add(optionName);
        //listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) => { await DisplayAlert("Tapped", e.Item.ToString() + " was selected.", "OK"); ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; };
        //this.Content = listView;

        Label valuelabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "0",
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            FontSize = 30,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        Stepper stepper = new Stepper
        {
            Minimum = 0,
            Maximum = 10,
            Increment = 1,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand

        };


        stepper.ValueChanged += (sender, e)=>
        {
            valuelabel.Text = String.Format(" {0:F1}", e.NewValue);
            movieamount = stepper.Value.ToString();

        };



        Picker payment = new Picker
        {
            Title = "Payment Method",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand

        };
         var options1 = new List<string> {"Visa", "MasterCard", "AmericanExpress", "Free",};

         foreach (string optionName in options1) payment.Items.Add(optionName);
        payment.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            paymentSelected = payment.Items[payment.SelectedIndex];
        };

        //TimePicker was here



        Label totalLabel = new Label

        {

            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            FontSize = 40,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic


        };

        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker
        {
            Format = "D",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,

        };

        //---Handle Inline---

        datePicker.DateSelected += (object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            //eventValue.Text = e.NewDate.ToString();
            dateSelected = e.NewDate.ToString();

        };

        TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker

        {
            Format = "T",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand

        };
        // set inline handler

        timePicker.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == TimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName)

            {
                timeSelected = timePicker.Time.ToString();
            };

        };

        Button button = new Button

        {
              Text = "Submit",

              FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Button)),
              HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
              VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill

        };

        button.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
        {
          totalLabel.Text = "You have ordered " + movieamount  + " " +
          pickmovie + " \n You will be paying with " + paymentSelected + " " +
          "Your delivery will be delivered at " + dateSelected + " " +  timeSelected;


        }; 





        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =

            {
                myListView,
                picker,
                payment,
                valuelabel,
                stepper,
                datePicker,
                totalLabel,
                timePicker,
                button,


            }

        };
        BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;
        this.Content = stackLayout;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: is the problem that the app doesn't deploy at all, or that you can't see your ListView?  Do you get any error or exceptions?

Comment: Hi, there is no error messages, however 7 warnings.The$(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll(7.1) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (5.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
The "XamlCTask" task could not be initiaized with its input parameters.   Some of this I think can be ignored.